# Log the log4net logs in file if the database is down

Tags: c#, log4net

Is there way to configure the log4net is such a way that, if the database is down or could not able to connect to database exceptions should log into file(only if the database is having problem). Currently i am able to write for both database and file.

Comment: have a look at this **SO** answer for your question[How to log this exception if log4net appender fails to write in the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3067845/2417602)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to log this exception if log4net appender fails to write in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065179/how-to-log-this-exception-if-log4net-appender-fails-to-write-in-database)